# Create/renew signing certificate for sideloaded UWP builds?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, code-signing

Some months ago I inherited a UWP project from a departing developer. I am not an expert in UWP or Windows programming but I was given instructions for making side-load builds to deliver to our customer, which involes signing the build with a certificate.

This certificate has now expired. I followed instructions for creating a new certificate, but what I ended up with is a self-signed certificate that isn't recognized by my customer's machine, so he can't install the build.

I have what I think is a valid store certificate: at least, I know that I can make and deploy store builds. But I can't use the store certificate to make side-load builds.

I'm not really familiar with all of the rules regarding code signing for this type of application. Is it possible to generate a trusted certificate that can sign a side-load build? Would it be based on my store certificate? Or if not, what is the correct procedure?

Is there a simple way to just renew the expired certificate that I have? Do I need a certificate at all, or can I just distribute an unsigned build?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

> > renew signing certificate for sideloaded UWP builds

1. Re-new your expired Your_TemporaryKey. pfx. Double-click your manifest file and choose Packaging tab, click the 'Choose Certificate' button->Create, you can fill the password or not, it's optional. The temporary key here has nothing to do with the previous Store key.
2. After creating the certificate, open the folder where the certificate is located, double-click it and select 'trusted people' to install the certificate.
3. Double-click your appxbundle and install it successfully.

Comment: Is there a way to create a certificate that doesn't have to be installed first?

Comment: No, for uwp you always need to install the certificate first.